# Overloading virtual functions of the same name from different base classes. Is it possible?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions, overriding

The title is probably confusing.

Suppose we have the following set up;

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void fn() = 0;
};

class B
{
public:
    virtual int fn() {};
};

class C: public A, public B
{
};
```

Is there any way to define `A::fn` in `class C`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**. This is not possible. It will always conflict with either of the `fn()`.

The syntax of `fn()` are different,

```
void fn();  // in A
```

and in `B` is,

```
int fn();  // in B
```

You have to make those syntax same in `A` and `B` to let `C` implement the `fn()`. [Demo](http://www.ideone.com/35I4e).

Answer (score 4):

There's no way in `C` to specify that one of the `C::fn()`
implementations overloads `A::fn()` (and presumably another overloads
`B::fn()`).  What you can do, however, is introduce an intermediate
class which “renames” the functions, something like:

```
class RemapA : public A
{
    virtual void fnInA() = 0;
public:
    virtual void fn()
    {
        fnInA();
    }
};

class RemapB : public B
{
    virtual int fnInB() = 0;
public:
    virtual int fn()
    {
        return fnInB();
    }
};

class C : public RemapA, public RemapB
{
    virtual void fnInA() { /* ... */ }
    virtual void fnInB() { /* ... */ }
    //  ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read my answer to the following question: [Implement two functions with the same name but different, non-covariant return types due to multiple abstract base classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371953/implement-two-functions-with-the-same-name-but-different-non-covariant-return-t/11373151#11373151)
In short: Yes, with some restrictions on calling it. It can be called as an A (pointer or reference) or a B (pointer or reference), but not as a C, as that would be ambiguous.